# Is there anyway to bypass domain redirection?

Tags: php, html, url, redirect

I have a script that extract the temp direct url from another hosts like this:
http://example.com/tempfolder/tempid/fileName.mp4

If I output the URL as a href like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/tempfolder/tempid/fileName.mp4">Temp Direct URL</a>
```

When I click, it will redirect me to the another URL or return as error 403.
But when I copy that url and paste it into the browser, It's works perfectly.

I think my domain might be block/blacklist from that hosts (My script still works when I run on another domain).

Question is: "Is there anyway to bypass that redirect?".

Comment: is the missing `"` at the end of the URL in your code too?

Comment: No, only on this post, my typo. I've re-correct the post.

Comment: I've tried to run my script on another domain. It's works perfectly!

Comment: There is a chance that you might need some cookies or the right `agent` to make that work. Try logging the network request in the developer console and then try recreating it.

Comment: I don't think that related to agent or cookies. It's will works if I copy and paste that output url to browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research on internet, finally I have my own answer.
Put this to head tag, and everything works perfect.

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
```